# Akka logging pattern unchangeable

Tags: scala, logging, akka, slf4j, actor

just building a small actor application for my bachelor thesis and now I am trying to add some logging.

For logging inside the actorsystem I want to use the logging akka provides with logback-classic in the background.
The logging is working well so far but the pattern inside the actor system doesn't change when I change it in the logback.xml

Anyone an idea how to change the pattern that is global and used by logging via slf4j and logging inside the actorsystem?

**log output outside the actor system:**

```
2014-07-11 13:03:09 INFO  model.AccessLayer : New Object 10 with id:188586187441591506  `
2014-07-11 13:03:09 INFO  model.AccessLayer : New Object 11 with id:188586187442115794`
```

**log output from inside the actor system:**

```
[INFO] [07/11/2014 13:03:09.199] [EBTreeSimulation-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://EBTreeSimulation/user/nodeA] nodeA[InsertNewObject] received new object:188586187441591506, 188586187441591506, 10 

[INFO] [07/11/2014 13:03:09.199] [EBTreeSimulation-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://EBTreeSimulation/user/nodeB] nodeB[InsertNewObject] received new object:188586187441591506, 188586187441591506, 10
```

**Logger initialisation for slf4j:**

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

```
class AccessLayer[T](communicationLayer:ActorRef, actors:List[ActorRef]) {
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[AccessLayer[T]])
  ....
}
```

**Logger initialisation for actorSystem:**

```
import akka.event.Logging
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object SimulationMaster extends App{
   val system = ActorSystem("EBTreeSimulation", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("akka"))
   val log = Logging.getLogger(system,this)
   ....
}

import akka.event.Logging

class TreeActor[T](communication:ActorRef) extends Actor {
   val log = Logging(context.system,this)
   ....

}
```

**logback.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>./logs/myLog.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/myLog.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level %X{sourceThread} %logger{10} [%file:%line]: %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!--<target>System.out</target>-->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<!--<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />-->
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

**application.conf:**

```
akka {
    # Loggers to register at boot time (akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger logs
    # to STDOUT)
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    #event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]

    loglevel = "INFO"   
    stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor {
       provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
        default-dispatcher {
            throughput = 10
        }
    }
    remote {
        netty.tcp.port = 4711
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem might have to do with this line `ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("akka")`.  Try and change it to just `ConfigFactory.load`.  That way it sees the child 'akka' element and gets the modified logging config from it.

Comment: Great solved the problem! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that akka load the default config instead of the customized one. To solve the Problem the loading of the configuration had to be changed:

import akka.event.Logging
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

```
object SimulationMaster extends App{
   val system = ActorSystem("EBTreeSimulation", ConfigFactory.load)
   val log = Logging.getLogger(system,this)
   ....
}
```

Thanks to cmbaxter!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have effectively answered this question.  However, I had several other related issues.

To help debug the problem, you can log the ActorSystem configuration as follows:

```
object SimulationMaster extends App{
   val conf = ConfigFactory.load
   val system = ActorSystem("EBTreeSimulation", conf)
   val log = Logging.getLogger(system,this)
   log info conf.getObject("akka").toString
   ....
}
```

In this output I saw that the `akka.loggers` was still set to some default logger instead of the slf4j logger.  Looking further into the configuration, I found that the slf4j logger was set, but it was set to the **singular** `akka.logger`.  I pluralized it and then everything started working.